# Cloned Repo Error Message... trying to run dev build

Tags: javascript, github, dependencies, portfolio, repo

I cloned a project from github, used npm i, and npm start and I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQL5J.png). For troubleshooting purposes, I upgraded Node.js to 20.5.1, upgraded dependencies, and cleared cache. This is the [json files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RFdq.png) I'm working with. Please let me know any tips on how to troubleshoot.

Thanks

See Above. I need to figure out how to troubleshoot this error.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried running `npm audit fix --force` after `npm i`